# $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] evaluates to to 'GET' by default

Tags: php, http-post, http-get

Been doing a bit of digging about this, but, no luck finding information

I'm trying to check whether a form has been submitted and if it is either `GET` or `POST`. So essentially I use:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
```

or

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

However, I find that if I don't submit any form, and just go to the page directly - a simple HTTP Request, the `REQUEST_METHOD` is `GET`. What gives? Is this by design? If so then I can't use the former statement to check whether a form has been submitted via GET. Seems a bit redundant...

Someone with a bit more knowledge please explain this to me, that would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In case it helps: I usually check with count($_GET) or count($_POST).

Comment: @elcodedocle `empty($_POST)` and `empty($_GET)` are slightly more efficient than `count()` but not by much and that is definitely micro-optimisation.

Comment: @DaveRandom good pick up thanks.

Comment: @DaveRandom thanks, it sure is an interesting optimization when talking intensive use, I will take it on account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically most HTTP requests are GET requests.

you can use `if($_POST)` to check if it's a POST. (That's the array with POST data in it. All pages have `$_GET` set, so `if($_GET)` won't work to tell if it's a GET)

However, `if(count($_GET)>0)` will tell you if there is $_GET data.

You can have both POST and GET data though, by sending a POST request to a URL with GET data in it (i.e. `http://example.unreal?GetData=4&OtherData=no`)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I will use count from now on ++++

Answer (score 2):

Simply going to a page through your browser or clicking a link IS a GET request.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered same problem and resolved by this:
When the form action is set as `iprofile?r=search`, the request method is always GET and all input data in the form are lost. But when i set the action to `iprofile/?r=search`, the request method become POST.

Maybe you can also check your action URL.